# Can I access strings from a .wxl localization file from a custom action with WiX?

Tags: c++, windows, wix, windows-installer

I have the following WiX markup that instructs the MSI installer to call a custom action from the included DLL:

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_SetProperties_Finalize" 
        Property="CA_OnInstallFinalize" 
           Value="[Installed],[REINSTALL],[UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE],[REMOVE]" />

<CustomAction Id='CA_OnInstallFinalize' 
       BinaryKey='CADll' 
        DllEntry='msiOnInstallFinalize' 
         Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no' />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='CA_SetProperties_Finalize' 
          Before='InstallFinalize'></Custom>
  <Custom Action='CA_OnInstallFinalize' 
           After='CA_SetProperties_Finalize'></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Binary Id='CADll' SourceFile='Sources\ca-installer.dll' />
```

And the DLL itself has the following C++ code for the custom action:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:msiOnInstallFinalize=_msiOnInstallFinalize@4")

extern "C" UINT __stdcall msiOnInstallFinalize(MSIHANDLE hInstall) 
{
    //Do the work
    if(doWork(hInstall) == FALSE)
    {
        //Error, cannot continue, display end-user message...
        PMSIHANDLE hRecord = MsiCreateRecord(0);
        MsiRecordSetString(hRecord, 0, TEXT("Error cannot continue!"));
        MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE(INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR + MB_OK), hRecord);

        return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
    }

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you see the end-user message is hard-coded. In my actual WiX markup I use localization .wxl file for strings as such:

```
<Property Id="ARPCONTACT" Value="!(loc.ContactInfo)" Secure="yes" />
```

And then, for instance, `lang_en-us.wxl` file would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  <String Id="ContactInfo">To get hold of me yell out of the window...</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

So I was curious, is there any way to access those localization strings from the .wxl file in my C++ custom action code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Windows Installer database and session tables from your custom action. A common table to access is the Properties table.

As you know, WiX will build the database tables with localized values for each culture it builds the .msi for. So, yes, the localization strings can be accessed, for example, as property values.

(But, no, a custom action cannot read them directly from a .wxl file unless you use the .wxl in a different way. The .wxl files in your project are not normally included in the installer except as individual localized string reference replacements.)

It other words, you're probably overthinking this. Just set and use properties with localized values were appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Can you show how exactly one can read properties from a custom action code? All I can access is `CustomActionData`.

Comment: You can use the whole Windows Installer API in a custom action. It's available as C or COM. As COM, it's accessible in .NET with `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Windows.Installer"))`, or with WiX's wrapper, DTF. WiX also provides a library to assist writing custom actions in C. The underlying function you need is [MsiGetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370134(v=vs.85).aspx). See the documentation for an example.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. The issue with that approach is that if the custom action is running elevated the only property one can access in a read-only fashion is `CustomActionData`.